# Xpath query for finding nested element

Tags: php, xpath, simple-html-dom

I am having a difficult time figuring out why I'm not getting any result with this basic 2-part xpath example, and I've used Chrome's XPath Helper to confirm that the 2nd xpath Query is indeed correct and does return the row I am seeking.
Can someone shed some light into why it's producing an empty result? In this example, I'm expecting to get the table row with BNY as the currency code, which is China's Yuan Renminbi. In general, I would want the table row data for any currency code that is requested, or an empty result if the currency code is not in the table.

I've also tried performing the 2nd xpath query immediately after the html load (bypassing the xpath query to retrieve JUST the table), but that's returning ALL the rows. I feel like there's something fundamentally wrong I'm doing here, but I haven't been able to discover it, as Chrome's XPath Helper works fine.

```
    $ccode = 'CNY';
    // Create a DOM object
    $html = new simple_html_dom();

    $url = "http://www.xe.com/symbols.php";
    // Load HTML from a URL
    $html->load_file($url);

    $table = $html->find('table.currencySymblTable', 0);        
    $xpathQuery = '//table/tbody/tr/td[2][text() = "'.$ccode.'"]/..';
    echo $xpathQuery;
    $tr = $table->find($xpathQuery);
    print_r($tr);
```

Comment: can you tell use what you are trying to do..?

Comment: I've provided a couple more sentences to the end of my post to explain what I'm trying to do, thanks.

Comment: SimpleHtmlDom is not a real W3C DOM implementation. Different API and no Xpath (just a subset of CSS selectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong `currency code` it should be **CNY** and you are using wrong

> **XPATH** should be this `table[@class="currencySymblTable"]/tr/td[2][text()="CNY"]/parent::tr`

```
 <?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$htmlContent = file_get_contents("http://www.xe.com/symbols.php");
$object = new DOMDocument();
$object->loadHTML($htmlContent);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($object);
$xpathQuery = '//table[@class="currencySymblTable"]/tr/td[2][text()="CNY"]/parent::tr';
$results = $xpath->query($xpathQuery);
foreach ($results as $result)
{
    print_r($result);
}
```

**Output:**

```
DOMElement Object
(
    [tagName] => tr
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => tr
    [nodeValue] => China Yuan RenminbiCNYÂ¥Â¥165a5  info
    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
    [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
    [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => tr
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => China Yuan RenminbiCNYÂ¥Â¥165a5    info
)
```

Comment: That's actually just a typo, CNY doesn't work either. Also tried /parent::tr instead of /.. at the end of the query, still comes up empty.

Comment: Yep, it works. I'm trying to use simple_html_dom, but that's fine, I don't really care. Thank you!

Comment: /.. at the end works as well. Not sure why simple_html_dom isn't playing well with xpath query, as I've used it in the past, but I just really need the end result, not how I achieved it. Thanks again.

Comment: @MikeT which end result?